# i need use sql_variant in entity framework code first

Tags: entity-framework-5, sql-variant

i have to define dynamic parameters value in database for invoke my methods in C# by these parameters.
BTW,i just use simple varibale such as int,bool,string,datetime....
but unfortunately i can't get value from sql_variant field to object in my model.

i use EF code First 5 and SQL 2008 Server

Comment: It is not supported - use direct SQL through ADO.NET.

Comment: So you also can't use `sql_variant`. One way to get result from [sql_variant](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137509/Reading-sql_variant-in-Entity-Framework) is this work around but it doesn't work with code first - you need EDMX.

Comment: do you have any suggestion to do it with code first and without SQL_Variant ?